# Expect script create list and append to it

Tags: list, automation, scripting, tcl, expect

I'm currently trying to create a list into an expect script and to fill it later

I can declare and initialize the list as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set matchList [list test1 test2]

foreach elem $matchList {
    puts $elem
}
```

Which gives the following result

```
$ ./tmp.expect 
test1
test2
```

However I can't find a way to correctly append a new string to the list

I have tried several syntax without being able to find the proper way

- `set matchList [list $matchList test3]`

Considers that 'test1 test2' is the first element and 'test3' the second

```
$ ./tmp.expect 
test1 test2
test3
```

- `set matchList [list [foreach elem $matchList { puts $elem } ] test3]`

Set the third element as an empty string and 'test3' is the fourth element

```
$ ./tmp.expect 
test1
test2

test3
```

- `set matchList [list [foreach elem $matchList { puts $elem } ]test3]`

By removing the space after the `foreach` block The list is correctly filled. However it seems a bit overkill to do such a simple task.

```
$ ./tmp.expect 
test1
test2
test3
```

Does anybody knows how to correctly fill a list element by element into an expect script ?

Comment: Take a look at the `lappend` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it works well. You should add an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Not the appropriate answer for this task, but when you need to expand a list into it's individual elements, use [the `{*}` syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) -- `set matchList [list {*}$matchList test3]` -- but of course, use `lappend` here.

Comment: Expect uses Tcl. You need to learn Tcl first. http://tcl.tk/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to add an element to the end of a list in Tcl is to use [`lappend`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lappend.htm); the first argument is the name of a variable containing a list, and the second and subsequent arguments are values to append:

```
lappend matchList test3
```

That works even when values have metacharacters embedded within them.